# How to change ImageView's background AFTER setting up ImageAdapter?

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter

I have this code:

```
popular_gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.popular_gridview);
image_adapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
popular_gridview.setAdapter(image_adapter);

ImageView iv = (ImageView) image_adapter.getView(3, null, null);
iv.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.star);
```

First three lines works, fourth and fifth not. I want to change one item in my adapter after setting it up, but nothing happens. Maybe someone know how to do this? I will be very grateful for solution. Thanks!

Comment: is your code compiled without any errors ? i am getting error at last line.

Comment: Yes, everything works without exceptions, but my adapter doesn't change image.

Comment: For **setImageDrawable** method, the argument should be Drawable not Resource Id. Check it once, this is the error i am getting

Comment: I changed to setImageResource and still no errors and still doesn't work. It must be something related to adapter or gridview.

Comment: The procedure you did is not right way to achieve your requirement. We have to modify the Adapter class according this requirement. Let me know how you are adding Images in getView() inside the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with one of my projects.
Here is the solution I found :

```
View[] myViews = new View[4];
ImageView img1 = new ImageView(context);
myViews[0] = img1;

image_adapter adapter = new image_adapter (context, myViews);
popular_gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

img1.invalidate();
img1.forceLayout();
```

Hope it helps !